# Beautiful soup find_all on ul with specified class returns none regardless of specified class. Find_all works on a different ul in the same program

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

trying to search craigslist across multiple cities
first time using find all is to grab each city and save link, works no problem.
Second time using find all is in a for loop, idea is city by city we save the single link needed. Unfortunaley it saves none every time. Using find will save the first list item which shows me it kind of works and I must be doing something wrong with the find_all method. Ive used find_all method a few times in single loops with no issue, is there a problem because Im calling from nested for loop? Find works no problem though...

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(cityPage, 'lxml')
    cities = soup.find('ul', class_="height6 geo-site-list")
    #saves link to each city in list 
    city_hyperlink = cities.find_all('li')
    for city in city_hyperlink:
        # for each city, goal is to extract 1 list item before going to next city 
        #make url link for new soup object using each new city link
        so = requests.get(city.a['href']).text
        soupy = BeautifulSoup(so, 'lxml')
        #save ul class so we can find specific list item we need 
        car_col_class = soupy.find("ul", id="sss0")
        
       #issue starts here, this returns none. find() pulls first list item but we need 
       specific one down the list 
       #ignores the specified class tag, just returns none  
       for col in car_col_class:
            search = car_col_class.find_all('li', class_="ata")
            #just a test to see if it found correct url 
            print(search)
```

Comment: Hello @imhungry, I suggest to do a printing of the `.status_code` just to see if you're getting `200` probably you're having `None` values is it's responding to you a different form of `html`

Comment: Also you could you provide a sample link so we can have a look also of the site & its `HTML` , Thanks!

Comment: @StackOffended here is the site, I am trying to pull the href link from the cars and trucks category https://bakersfield.craigslist.org/. This is the first one though, the idea is it would pull the cars and trucks category from every city listed on this page https://geo.craigslist.org/iso/us/CA.

Comment: @StackOffended I solved i believe by using find(data- tag) as opposed to find(class).

Answer (score 1):

Searching by data attribute as opposed to class name solved the problem. No idea why but it works

```
search = car_col_class.find(attrs={"data-cat": "cta"})
```

as opposed to

```
search = car_col_class.find('li', class= "cta" )
```